# Switching to Full Site using PHP Sessions - Styles Not Loading

Tags: php, html

I have an issue switching from a mobile site to a full site using sessions; the styles on the full site don't load unless I refresh the page, at which point they load. On my mobile page, I have a link to the full site:

```
<a href="link_to_full_site/?v=full">Full Site</a>
```

I'm using a common header for all of my pages (which may be what's causing my issue, I'm not sure). Either way, my header code is as follows:

```
<?php

session_start();  // start session - sessions are being used to detect mobile vs. full site.

?>

<?php

// check to see if user has chosen full site.
if (isset($_GET['v']) && $_GET['v'] == 'full') {
    $_SESSION['v'] = 'full';
}

// if user hasn't chosen full site, redirect them to mobile site.
if (!isset($_SESSION['v']) || (isset($_SESSION['v']) && $_SESSION['v'] != 'full')) {
   // mobile browser detection code from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com
    $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://link_to_mobile');
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Dynamically set page's title using php -->
    <title>
        <?php 
            if (isset($title)) {
                echo "Website | $title";
            }
            else {
                echo "My Website";
            } 
        ?>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <!-- check to see if user is on mobile -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
```

As you can see, the checking is done at the top of the page - so I'd assume that the styles should load and the page should display correctly. This isn't the case - the stylesheets are not loading, causing issues. If I refresh the page, the styles display correctly.

Also possibly of note - this website is located in a subfolder, it's a student hosting account so I have to organize within subfolders. The folder organization is essentially public_html/website and public_html/website/mobile. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
When viewing the html code in chrome's console, it appears that when I click the link to the full site, it's getting stuck halfway between the mobile site and the full version. It begins with the html for the mobile site and then there's a . I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: What Browser did you test this on? If it's a mobile one, that's your problem.

Comment: I get the same result when testing in a desktop browser.

Comment: It's funny that your Browser does not recognize that, even though your CSS in cached, you've changed pages.

Comment: Yeah I've tested across multiple browsers and different computers - not sure what the issue is here. If you see my edit, it appears to be loading the full site using a <base> tag for some reason, do you happen to know what would cause this?

Comment: That's the problem, `<base>` specifies the base folder. Please show the `<base>` tag in your code.

Comment: I understand that, I just don't know why it's using this method; I'm simply linking to the page like I'd link to any other using an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Strange solution here - adding target = "_self" to the anchor tag linking to the desktop version of the page solved the problem. I say strange because target="_self" is the default, but I won't argue with results!

```
<a href="link_to_full_site" target="_self">Full Site</a>
```